# how to access files in default package from native android code (Codename One)

Tags: android, native, codenameone

Since I can't use [Media](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/media/Media.html) objects for playing when the app is **not** running but I have to play media files in that state, I need a solution to access media files from native code and reference them for native media players (either via path or Inputstream). I still want to put the relevant files in that way that it won't become a burden to access them from native iOS code.
There are two options I was thinking about, but couldn't really manage in my implementation.

1. Put the relevant data files in the GuiBuilder's data section and access them over a [Resources](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/util/Resources.html) object (and call `getData(id)`). But when I try to create a `Resources` object over `Resources.open("/theme");` from native code on Android I get the following exception: `java.io.IOException: /theme not found`.
2. Keep the relevant data files in the default package and access them over `Class.getResourceAsStream` or `Class.getResource`. But I don't know how to point at those files. I tried various paths but without any success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you copy the media files to FileSystemStorage, it should be fairly easy to access on the native side.  You can just pass the path to your native interface.

That being said, I have developed a few CN1 apps with background audio without problem.  On iOS you just need to supply the `ios.background_modes=audio` build hint so that the app will be allowed to run in the background.

If you use the `Display.createBackgroundMedia()` method to create the media, then Android will also use a background service for playing the media.

Comment: the copying of the files to the FileSystemStorage helped me, and the advice concerning iOS is also relevant, thanks for that. But I'm stuck at my next step. The issue is that a lot of functionality of cn1 is not usable when the application is not running (even Log). My application's model is naturally serialized/deserialized using cn1's storage methods. This is unfortunately a problem when I try to deserialize my model (which contains crucial meta data for my media files) in native code (when the app is not running!). I somehow try to fix this by using NativeLookup, which also is not working..

Comment: .. in that case. Is there a possiblity to use NativeLookup over static callback methods when the app is not running?

Comment: What do you mean by "when the app is not running"?  Do you mean just running in the background?  When running in the background there are a lot of sharp corners.  When you're running in the background in native, there are even sharper corners and the solution will depend on the specifics.

Comment: yes exaclty. I meant that a service is independently running in the background (but uses the same model as the application).. indeed there are a lot of sharp corners, I had to experience..